# Emit explicit interface implementation of a property

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, typebuilder

#### Goals

So what I want to do, is creating a type at runtime with the `TypeBuilder` class. The interface of from which I want the runtime type to implement looks like the following.

```cs
public interface ITest
{
    int TestProperty { get; }
}
```

The type which should be generated should look like the following:

```cs
internal class Test : ITest
{
    int ITest.TestProperty { get => 0; }
}
```

The explicit implementation of the interface isn't really necessary, but that is what I found the most resources on.

---

#### Now to the actual code

```cs
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("AssemblyTest");
var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

var typeBuilder = module.DefineType("TestType", TypeAttributes.NotPublic | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class, null, new[] { typeof(ITest) });

var prop = typeBuilder.DefineProperty("ITest.TestProperty", PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, typeof(int), null);

var propGet = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ITest.get_TestProperty", MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final);

var propertyGetIL = propGet.GetILGenerator();

propertyGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
propertyGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

prop.SetGetMethod(propGet);

typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(propGet, typeof(ITest).GetProperty("TestProperty").GetGetMethod());

var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

Just as a short explanation of the code.

1. Creation of the DynamicAssembly/Module/Class
2. Create the Backing Field and the Property itself
3. Create the content of the Get method for the property
4. Mark the property as the [implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Emit_TypeBuilder_DefineMethodOverride_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_) of the interface
5. Create the new type

However the `CreateType` method throws the following at me:

> Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match.  Type: 'TestType'.  Assembly: 'AssemblyTest, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'

I am really not sure how I would implement the property and what the cause of this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the return type when you define the get method. You need to specify it using a [different overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethod?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Emit_TypeBuilder_DefineMethod_System_String_System_Reflection_MethodAttributes_System_Type_System_Type___) of `DefineMethod`:

```
var propGet = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ITest.get_TestProperty", 
  MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | 
  MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final,
  typeof(int), // <--- return type
  Type.EmptyTypes // <-- parameter types (indexers)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really forgot about the return type even tho I wrote those few lines multiple times.